# Pandas bfill manipulate value before filling

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use `bfill` on a pandas dataframe but I want the value to use for each backfill to be dependant on the values in the row.

Example input:

```
           type   val
2018-12-31    H     1
2019-03-31  NaN   NaN
2019-06-30    Q     2
2019-07-31  NaN   NaN
2019-08-31    H     3
2019-09-30    Y     4 
2019-12-31    Q     5
```

Expected output:

```
           type   val
2018-12-31    H     1
2019-03-31    Q     2  <-- Same as 2019-06-30
2019-06-30    Q     2
2019-07-31    Q     6  <-- Double 2019-08-31
2019-08-31    H     3
2019-09-30    Y     4
2019-12-31    Q     5
```

In this example, the backfilled value for `2019-07-31` is 6 because it has a `H` type, i.e. it's double the `(2019-08-31, H)` value. On the other hand, the backfilled value for `2019-03-31` is the same as the next row since that type is `Q`.

Rules:

- Type `H`: double the value for backfill
- Type `Q` and `Y`: keep the value for backfill
- All types: Set type to `Q`

I could not find any straightforward built in way of doing this. I need to do this on a very large dataframe so speed is important to me, and it's why I can't loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
# generate a series m, which contains 2 where the
# next value is H
m = df.type.eq('H').shift(-1).add(1).fillna(1)
# Fill missing values in type with H
df.type.fillna('H', inplace = True)
# fillna in val and mulitply with m
df['val'] = df.val.fillna(df.val.shift(-1) * m)
```

---

```
print(df)

            type  val
2018-12-31    H  1.0
2019-03-31    H  2.0
2019-06-30    Q  2.0
2019-07-31    H  6.0
2019-08-31    H  3.0
2019-09-30    Y  4.0
2019-12-31    Q  5.0
```

---

Where:

```
print(m)

2018-12-31    1
2019-03-31    1
2019-06-30    1
2019-07-31    2
2019-08-31    1
2019-09-30    1
2019-12-31    1
Name: type, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

First create mask for values multiple by `2` for rows with missing values and for backfilled `H` values:

```
m = df['type'].isna() & df['type'].bfill().eq('H')
```

Then back fill values of `val` and multiple by `2` by mask:

```
df['val'] = df['val'].bfill().mask(m, lambda x: x * 2)
```

Last replace missing value in `type` column:

```
df['type'] = df['type'].fillna('Q')
print (df)
           type  val
2018-12-31    H  1.0
2019-03-31    Q  2.0
2019-06-30    Q  2.0
2019-07-31    Q  6.0
2019-08-31    H  3.0
2019-09-30    Y  4.0
2019-12-31    Q  5.0
```